# Hold Shift to temporary change keyboard layout in Mac OS

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization

On a PC with multiple keyboard layouts, you can temporary switch to English by holding the Shift key.

Can I achieve this behavior on a Mac natively or with a third party extension?

I especially need this for Hebrew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MacOS Sierra, you can switch to US and back via caps lock if your other keyboard is for a non-Latin script (with some exceptions like Greek and Cyrillic).

There are certain Apple input sources like Hebrew PC which switch to Latin Qwerty via the Shift key.

Comment: I solved it by changing the layout from "Hebrew" to "Hebrew PC". Now holding the Shfit key changes the layout to English.
Thanks for the quick answer!